# Android Seekbar Thumb position

Tags: android

i want to place the thumb of the seek bar in android at extreme right corner which is by default at extreme left corner.Is it possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes.you can try this:

in xml:

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/seek"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dip"
        android:max="80"
        android:progress="80"      
        />
```

Also,programatically you can set it:

```
SeekBar sb=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek);
sb.setProgress(80); //you must set your maximum progress here,which you specified in your xml
```